# Realistic memory usage for MLT Framework project?

Tags: video-processing, mlt

I am trying to render a video project that I created with `kdenlive`. It is about 50 minutes long and contains a dozen short 1080p video clips and several hundred still images (mostly 18MP). `melt` runs and proceeds to consume all 4GB of my RAM, at which point it is killed by the kernel.

I have tried both mlt 0.9.0 that came with Ubuntu 14.04, and I have tried the latest version, 0.9.8, that I compiled myself. No difference.

Is this indicative of a problem with `melt`, or is it just not realistic to render this kind of project with only 4GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have 4 GB free RAM before launching melt? I do expect a project of that complexity and resolution to consume near 4 GB. You can readily remove half the project contents and make a test to see how it compares. There is a workaround that requires editing the project XML to set autoclose=1 on the playlists, but that is not set by default since it only works with sequential processing and will break handling in a tool that seeks such as Kdenlive.

Comment: Can you advise what part of the XML to modify? I tried adding child elements `<property name="autoclose">1</property>` to playlist elements but I get the "Failed to load" message on the `.mlt` file. Also tried adding this to `producer` elements; same result.

Comment: You did it correctly by adding a property element as a child of the playlist list element. Maybe you made some typo; it works for me. Another way is to add "autoclose=1" as an attribute of the playlist element. Adding it to the producer does nothing.

Comment: you were right, a thinko on my part. Workaround worked nicely, max memory usage with autoclose was ~2.5GB. Thanks for your help, and for your work on MLT!